# C# Redirect Console Output - UTF-8 Encoding

Tags: c#, encoding, utf-8, process

Im running a little tool that does some network-sniffing and data collection but is unstable due to its nature using SharpPCap. The base of this tool isnt written by me (I did edit it to fit my needs tho), instead I had to build my application around it in order to make it work.

Right now the one big problem im facing is UTF-8 Encoding.

The process actually doing the work is beeing started by the Main-Process

```
Process WorkerProc = new Process();
WorkerProc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
WorkerProc.StartInfo.FileName = @"Worker.exe";
WorkerProc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
WorkerProc.StartInfo.Arguments = Argument;
WorkerProc.StartInfo.StandardOutputEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;
WorkerProc.StartInfo.StandardErrorEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;
WorkerProc.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Normal;
WorkerProc.OutputDataReceived += OnOutputDataReceived;
WorkerProc.Start();
WorkerProc.BeginOutputReadLine();
```

This process later writes its Data using Console.WriteLine(StuffandThings) which is beeing redirect to the Main-Process.

Is there a better way of doing this, then using Console.WriteLine? I figured its probably wrong but I dont know of any better way.

The Data the Worker Process receives is Encoded in UTF-8 to beginn with (Its also writing it to a local logfile which works fine).

This is how im writing the Data to the Main-Process

```
var utf8 = Encoding.UTF8;
byte[] utfBytes = utf8.GetBytes(INPUT);
string message = utf8.GetString(utfBytes, 0, utfBytes.Length);
Console.WriteLine(message);
```

The Error must be somewhere here, but I just dont know what it is. 
The Main-Process displays the Data in the Console and also sends it to a Log-Server using Log4Net.

How can I ensure, that the data still is UTF-8 Encoded?
Any better way then Console.WriteLine()?

Thanks!

Comment: Is the worker process something you control? Does it have to be a separate executable and can't be brought in to the main application as a class?

Comment: Is `INPUT` a string? Would setting `Console.OutputEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;` work for you?